# How to Get Attachment from SharePoint List in Azure Function using Webhooks

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, webhooks, remote-debugging

We have a SharePoint list that contains a large PDF attachment and have set up an Azure Webhook to notify an Azure Function App of a change to the SharePoint list and would like to have the ability to check for and parse a PDF attachment.

I am fairly still new to this type of development, but have found an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/sharepoint-webhooks-using-azure-functions) that I followed, and our test currently seems to be triggering an event in our Azure Function and can see that the trigger is successful:

**Monitor Invocation:**
[image]

The code that I've implemented is pretty much verbatim from the above link example and it appears that most of the functionality is currently simply writing out log information, however I've not been able to find many examples of detailed implementation scenarios using SharePoint Lists to get an attachment from a SharePoint List.

Should we be getting our attachment data after reading in the request into a StreamReader object here?

```
 var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

**Full Code Context:**

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
    using System.Net;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req,
      ICollector<string> outputQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
      log.LogInformation($"Webhook was triggered!");

      // Grab the validationToken URL parameter
      string validationToken = req.Query["validationtoken"];

      // If a validation token is present, we need to respond within 5 seconds by
      // returning the given validation token. This only happens when a new
      // webhook is being added
      if (validationToken != null)
      {
        log.LogInformation($"Validation token {validationToken} received");
        return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(validationToken);
      }

      log.LogInformation($"SharePoint triggered our webhook...great :-)");
      //Is the attachment available via the content variable?
      var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
      log.LogInformation($"Received following payload: {content}");

      var notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel<NotificationModel>>(content).Value;
      log.LogInformation($"Found {notifications.Count} notifications");

      if (notifications.Count > 0)
      {
        log.LogInformation($"Processing notifications...");
        foreach(var notification in notifications)
        {
          // add message to the queue
          string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
          log.LogInformation($"Before adding a message to the queue. Message content: {message}");
          outputQueueItem.Add(message);
          log.LogInformation($"Message added :-)");
        }
      }

      // if we get here we assume the request was well received
      return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Added to queue");
    }

    // supporting classes
    public class ResponseModel<T>
    {
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
      public List<T> Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class NotificationModel
    {
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscriptionId")]
      public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientState")]
      public string ClientState { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expirationDateTime")]
      public DateTime ExpirationDateTime { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resource")]
      public string Resource { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tenantId")]
      public string TenantId { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "siteUrl")]
      public string SiteUrl { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "webId")]
      public string WebId { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubscriptionModel
    {
      [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
      public string Id { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientState", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
      public string ClientState { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expirationDateTime")]
      public DateTime ExpirationDateTime { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "notificationUrl")]
      public string NotificationUrl {get;set;}

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resource", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
      public string Resource { get; set; }
    }
```

I thought that I would try to debug this integration remotely since the code is running in the Azure Portal in order to set up watches and look into the HTTPRequest and StreamReader objects, however that's presented a whole new set of challenges and we've been unsuccessful there as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done here is fine, assuming you end up with an item placed on a queue. The real heavy lifting though will happen with the function that picks up the item off the queue. The json you send to the queue only notes that a change occurred; your queue receiver is going to have to authenticate and call back into SharePoint to fetch the data and do what it needs to do.

Read the [reference implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/webhooks-reference-implementation) section of the documentation you linked for a better explanation of the webhooks architecture.

I will add that developing Azure functions directly in the portal is going to be a nightmare for anything but trivial applications. And your application is not trivial. The ngrok based approach in the [Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks) section is good advice and really the only way to debug webhooks. Good luck!